# What is the distribution of $Y = e^X$ when $X$ is normal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is the distribution of $Y = e^X$ when $X$ is normally distributed?

Am I supposed to use characteristics function of normal random variable ?

Comment: You might find some information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: There are several different methods. What is stopping you here?

Comment: I don't know how to start! If it is using characteristic function its better, but I think the easiest one is using CDF of $X$ ?

Comment: This is the easiest approach for your case: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables

Comment: Have you not covered how to determine the density of a function of a continuous random variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you still haven't sorted it out: apply the formula in the Wiki link I gave you to get for $X \sim N(0,1)$
$$
X'_{y}=\frac{1}{y}\\
f_{X}(\varphi^{-1}(y))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{\log^2 y}{2}}
$$
Hence the distribution of $Y$ is 
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}y}e^{-\frac{\log^2 y}{2}}
$$
for $y>0$. Here I don't use the absolute value for $y$ because the pdf is defined for strictly positive values since $\log y$ doesn't exist for $y \leq 0$.