# Evaluate $\mathbb{E}[e^{e^x}] =\int_\mathbb{R}e^{e^x}f(x)dx$, where $f(x)$ is Gaussian kernel.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Trying to find $\mathbb{E}[e^{e^x}] =\int_\mathbb{R}e^{e^x}f(x)dx$, where $f(x)$ is the Gaussian density, ($\mu,\sigma^2$).

Can't seem to figure out where to start with this one. I've tried a few things, but nothing really comes close.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448962/what-is-the-distribution-of-y-ex-when-x-is-normal) tells the pdf of $e^x$, which means the expectation above is just the MGF evaluated at 1. Still having trouble computing that integral, though.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, this is the moment generating function for $Y=e^{X}$ evaluated at $1$. $Y$ has a log-normal distribution. Unfortunately the MGF, $M_{Y}(t)$, for the log-normal distribution is not defined for any positive $t$.

See, for example,  [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503165/proving-that-the-lognormal-distribution-has-no-moment-generating-function).